2d Image sequence wont display frame by frame images
I am new to blender and I couldn't find anything online to help me with my issue.
I imported an image sequence, but I would like to be able to modify the images.
there is no display of the images on the timeline, is there a way to show them? or better is there a way to upload image as a single frame? that way i could just do it for the rest of the image sequence and edit whatever i want
